# could not find generator 'devise:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rvm

I used `gem install devise` and `gem list` shows as following:

```
......
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6, 1.10.5)
byebug (6.0.2, 6.0.1, 6.0.0, 5.0.0)
cancan (1.6.10)
CFPropertyList (2.3.1, 2.2.8)
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
columnize (0.9.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
**devise** (3.5.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
......
```

Then I try to include devise into my rails project by `rails g devise:install` and here is the error:

```
could not find generator 'devise:install'
```

I am using RVM and is there any problem with that?

My env is `Rails 4.2.3`,`ruby 2.0.0p481`

Comment: you need to add `gem "devise"`to your gemfile of project actually. https://tommcfarlin.com/could-not-find-generator-devise-install/

Comment: @Athar   thanks a lot, my question was fool